# Python Script Unable to Get Cell Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to accomplish a seemingly simple task in Python. This is now my third SO post in as many days and I am embarassed.

I am hoping to open a csv file. I would like to loop through each row, and for every column in every row, if the value is NOT a 0 or a 1 (it is a "?"), to essentially rewrite that value with the value of the very last column. The very last column can never not be a 0 or 1. It will never be "?". I am not so much concerned with the print statement, as I am replacing the "?" (or non 0/1) value with the value in the last column.

I have attached an example csv file I am working with here:
http://www.sharecsv.com/s/7bef636c33054cae624928297146bae1/house.csv

If you are unable to view the link above, I have pasted a SAMPLE of the dataset below:

```
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,?,1.00
?,1.00,1.00,?,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,?,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,?,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,?,1.00,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,?,?,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,?,?,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,1.00,1.00,?,?,1.00
0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,?,?,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,?,1.00,1.00,?,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,?,0.00,?,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,?,0.00,?,1.00
1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,?,1.00,1.00,1.00,?,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,?,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,?,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,?,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,?,?,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,?,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,?,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,0.00
1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00
1.00,?,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,?,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00
1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,?,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,?,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,0.00
1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,?,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,?,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,?,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,?,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00
0.00,?,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,?,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,?,?,0.00
1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,?,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,?,1.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,?,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,0.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,?,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,?,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00
1.00,?,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,0.00
1.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,?,0.00
1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00
```

Here is my current codes:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('house1.csv'), delimiter = ',')
counter = 0

for row in reader:
    # print("Opened Reader")
    currVal = row[:-1]
    counter = counter + 1
    # print("set values")
    for column in row:
        questioncount = 0
        # print("Looping columns")
        if (column != 0 or column != 1):
            questioncount = questioncount + 1
            # This is where I should overwrite the value
        print("Row " + str(counter) + " has " + str(questioncount) + " question marks ")
```

I don't understand why I am having so much difficulty. Currently, the output of Pycharm is that it says every single row and column has a question mark, which is not true.

```
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 1 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 2 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 3 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 4 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 5 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 6 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 7 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 8 has 1 question marks 
Row 9 has 1 question marks 
Row 9 has 1 question marks 
Row 9 has 1 question marks 
Row 9 has 1 question marks 
Row 9 has 1 question marks 
Row 9 has 1 question marks 
Row 9 has 1 question marks 
Row 9 has 1 question marks 
Row 9 has 1 question marks 
...
Row 435 has 1 question marks
```

I would hope that given a line like 
`0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,?,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00` 
this python script would turn that line into 
`0.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.00,1.00,1.00`

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @Eshaka I already included an external link to whee I have it, but I just edited the question to include a chunks.

Comment: i see thanks, if you can u can type a line about the expected output too

Comment: If this is your actual code, your ```print``` statement is not indented properly. It's just printing the same line for every row and every column, bypassing your if block altogether.

Comment: @kerwei this is my actual code, and I can adjust the print statement. Thank you for noticing my error. I am however mostly focused on trying to replace the "?" values and don't even really plan on printing anything, as indicated in the question body.

Comment: ```questioncount``` should also be outside the nested for block.

Comment: Haven't looked at the logic, but this line is suspect:  if (column != 0 or column != 1).  That will ALWAYS be true.  I bet that's not what you want.  Did you mean 'and'?  I'm guessing that that's your problem.

Comment: @Steve, I think so, Steve. Sorry about that mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has got two bugs. The first one is that you check if a `column` doesn't equal to integers `0` or `1`, but `column` contains a string value. The second one, the initialization of the `questioncount` variable and a call of `print` function should take place out of the for-loop. Here is a working code:

```
import csv


rows = []

with open('house.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    counter = 0

    for row in reader:
        counter = counter + 1
        questioncount = 0

        for i, column in enumerate(row):

            if column == '?':
                questioncount = questioncount + 1
                row[i] = row[-1]

        rows.append(row)
        print('Row {i} has {q} question marks'.format(i=counter, q=questioncount))


with open('house1.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

P.S.: I've updated the code so that now it saves another file with question marks being replaced.

Comment: Hi, @constt. Thank you for this. I just tested it and the print statement works great, awesome! However, as my initial question actually requested, I care not so much for the print statement, as I do for being able to replace a question mark value with the value in the last column. So, I am unable to select you as answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix to your problem:

```
if not (column == '1.00' or column == '0.00'):
```

You were checking if the **string** values (from csv file) '1.00' or '0.00' are equal to the **integer** values (in your if statement) 1 or 0.

Also, you should apply 'not' to the two checks at once otherwise your logic falls through.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of issues:

1. You're reading the .csv, but the contents will be read as strings, not as floats, so your comparison `if (column != 0)` will always be true.
2. As a result, you always count 1 question mark, which you then proceed to print once for every column, as the `print` statement is in the column loop, not the row loop.
3. You are assigning the last value to `currVal`, but never using it.

Since your code is looking for question marks, perhaps you should not check whether a column isn't 1 or 0, but whether it is '?' instead?

Your code with those fixes:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('house1.csv'), delimiter=',')
counter = 0

for row in reader:
    counter = counter + 1
    questioncount = 0
    for column in row:
        if column == '?':
            questioncount += 1
    print("Row " + str(counter) + " has " + str(questioncount) + " question marks ")
```

To write the output you're looking for:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('simple.csv'), delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w', newline=''), delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    writer.writerow([column if column != '?' else row[-1:] for column in row])
```

Comment: interesting, thank you. Initially I tried looking for question marks but used `"?"` and not `'?'`. This definitely works, and is a clean solution (as always). Thank you for your suggestion. In a way of trying to go back to what my question was hopefully trying to ask, is how can I now write to the SAME csv file to replace those question marks with the value in the last column? That is what I was trying to achieve, just using print statements to test, as somebody suggested me to some days ago ;)

Comment: I've added that solution as well, keeping to your initial idea of opening the file and creating the reader and writer in one go. I would recommend using `with` if this code is part of a larger project. Note that you should get the same results regardless of using "?" or '?'.

Comment: Hi, @Grismar. Thank yo for this. Would you mind offering an explanation for `writer.writerow([column if column != '?' else '1.00' for column in row])` ? How does this grab the value of the last column in that row, doesn't this assume it is always 1? Also, this is note, just trying to create a suite of data cleaning tools and scripts I can use as I continue to practice with Python and Machine Learning.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I missed that aspect, you want '?' to become equal to the last. Let me update the example. Note that it now writes `row[-1:]` for each `?` it finds.

Answer (score 0):

use numpy to load

```
import numpy as np

my_data = np.genfromtxt('house.csv', delimiter=',')
# print(my_data)
for i in range(len(my_data)):

    row = my_data[i]
    # print(row)
    temp = row[-1]
    # print(temp)
    for j in range(len(row)):
        column = row[j]
        if not (column == 1 or column == 0) :

            my_data[i,j] = temp

# print(my_data)
np.savetxt("house.csv", my_data, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: is this what you want?